# Passing a JSON between PHP and Python

Tags: python, php, json, parameters

I need to pass data from a PHP page to a Python script and back.
I do it with a form that reminds to a page with this PHP code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Project</h1>
        <h2>Results</h2>

    </body>
</html>

<?php 
    $myHotel->name = $_POST["NAME"];
    $hotel_data = json_encode($myHotel); ;
    $command = escapeshellcmd("/var/www/html/test.py $hotel_data");
    $resultAsString = exec($command);
?>
```

The JSON is sent back from the Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json

print(sys.argv[1]);
```

The problem, is that i send a JSON string like this:

```
{"name":"Hotel Roma Sud"}
```

And I receive something like this:

```
{name:Hotel Roma Sud}
```

How can I receive a JSON string or manage to have one? I tried with exec(), json_encode, json_decode...
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the script calling the command to avoid `"` getting parsed out by the bash - in order to give Python correct JSON string the argument should look like this - `python test.py "{""name"":""Hotel Roma Sud""}"` - this way Python receives `'{"name":"Hotel Roma Sud"}'` for `argv[1]` which you can parse with `json.loads`. It's not very clean solution though, so I'd probably save the JSON string to a file from PHP and then load the contents of the file in Python, deleting the file afterwards if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I've found an elegant solution, hope it can be useful for anyone:

PHP file:

```
<p>Test JSON</p>
<?php
$loc = "Roma Sud";
$hotel = array("Name"=>$loc,"Stars"=>"3");
$param = base64_encode(json_encode($hotel));
$result = shell_exec("/var/www/html/test-json/test.py $param");
// echo "<strong>Hotel Name: </strong>";
$obj = json_decode($result);
print "<strong>Hotel Name: </strong>" . $obj->Name . "<br/>";
print "<strong>Stars: </strong>" . $obj->Stars . "<br/>";
?>
```

Python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import json
import base64
    
content = json.loads(base64.b64decode(sys.argv[1]))
print(json.dumps(content))
```